# Can I use Liferay portal on 1&1?

Tags: liferay, hosting

I know 1&1 has Liferay preinstalled but there's an extra fee to use it and I don't want to pay extra. Has anyone tried the "scenic route" and successfully used Liferay CE on 1&1?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This question is about programming and your question is far off topic - you can read about what's on topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thanks, Olaf. Is there another place I can ask my question or a resource you can point me to?

Comment: Search the stackexchange network. Plus, you might want to explain what that contact contains, rather than the name of a vendor that offers hundreds of different contracts